# edit form in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, codeigniter

I am newbie in  `CodeIgniter`. I have a `table` where data is showing. In each `row` there is an `edit button`. When the `edit button` is clicked, a `modal popup` will pop up and then you are able to edit it. What my problem is, is that I don't know how to attach a link of my `controller` behind the `image` so that I can send the `row id`  to the `controller`. I link my image(Edit) to the `modalpopup` in the `href` .. so how can I perform both the operations at the same time ..

This is my link in `form view`. As you can see, in the `href` tag, I link to `myModal` where the `edit form` is displayed, but I want that `edit form` to display against the `row`. So I have to link it to the `controller`, which I don't know how to do.

Is there a way to attach links to an image or there is another way ?

```
   <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">  
  <img src="images/32/edit.png" alt="Edit"></a></td>

     <div class="modal hide" id="myModal">
      //here all the form fields are displaying
```

Comment: can u make your question clear,maybe add screenshots. Also post your view and controller.

Comment: @arunu look i know how to do in controller and modal etc.i have to send an id to controller look if i dont talk about pop up .. lets say i want to edit a record ..so what i 'll do .. i put my controller link behind the edit link  ..right ? like that    <a href = "Controller/editemp/<?php echo $row->emp_id ?>">what this code do is simply send me to the edit page and then i am able to edit it now the second thing is  i want to popup a modal box where the form display with their values and then he is gonna edit it  and the modal form is also in the same page .. so what should i do? did u get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps
Create a link like this

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="<?php echo site_url('controllername/methodname/'.$id);?>">  
  <img src="images/32/edit.png" alt="Edit">
</a>
```

Now see controller class's method will be called on click. the id should be provided via loop.

Controller method

```
function methodname(){
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->load->model('modelname');
    $data['result'] = $this->modelname->getResord($id);
    $this->load->view('editform',$data);
}
```

And model method should fetch data with where condition

```
function modelmethod($id)
{
    return $this->db->where('id',$id)->get('tablename')->row();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your code ..but you didnt get it .. so as you mention the  link this href="<?php echo site_url('controllername/methodname/'.$id); now how am i gonna able to launch a popup Form whose link behind the img was that <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myform"> ... and at the bottom is <div id = myForm>

Comment: For pop up box i will recommend colorbox of jquery. Use it see its documentation. It is easy

Comment: u r not getting my point ...the colorbox or popup is at the bottom of the view page which i give them a div and hide it like and give  div to it like this  div id ="mycolorbox".. and above with the edit edit i mention the path in href tag like this href = mycolorbox..so when i click on the edit link it will instantly go into the mycolorbox ..do you get it ?

Comment: i am getting you point but you should know that on clicking image you need to write some javascript or jquery function that will fill the loaded view into the bottom div and display it while putting a layer on everything else so that user will interact only with pop up. For more read how colorbox works

Comment: so my question was i have attach a link of a pop up ..now then how am i gonna attach a controller path to this